# Why can't I inherit the constructors of a virtual base?

Tags: c++, gcc4.9

I'm trying to compile the following simple code using g++ 4.9.0:

```
struct A {
    explicit A(int x) { }
};

struct B : public virtual A {
    using A::A;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    B b(0);
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:10:10: error: use of deleted function ‘B::B(int)’
     B b(0);
          ^
main.cpp:6:14: note: ‘B::B(int)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     using A::A;
              ^
main.cpp:6:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
main.cpp:6:14: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:2:14: note: A::A(int)
     explicit A(int x) { }
              ^
main.cpp:2:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:1:8: note: constexpr A::A(const A&)
 struct A {
        ^
main.cpp:1:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:1:8: note: constexpr A::A(A&&)
main.cpp:1:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a compiler bug?

Comment: hm, [clang compiles it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24e4b21aeab3cf4d), not gcc

Comment: This is GCC bug [58751](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58751).

Comment: SO related is there (and actually is the source of the gcc file report) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399644/inheriting-constructors-and-virtual-base-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58751). §7.3.3 [namespace.udecl]/p3 requires that

> In a *using-declaration* used as a *member-declaration*, the
>   *nested-name-specifier* shall name a base class of the class being defined. If such a *using-declaration* names a constructor, the
>   *nested-name-specifier* shall name a direct base class of the class being defined...

`A` is a direct base of `B`, so `using A::A;` is allowed.

The standard specifies that (§12.9 [class.inhctor]/p8):

> An implicitly-defined inheriting constructor performs the set of
>   initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written
>   `inline` constructor for that class with a *mem-initializer-list* whose
>   only *mem-initializer* has a *mem-initializer-id* that names the base
>   class denoted in the nested-name-specifier of the using-declaration
>   and an expression-list as specified below, and where the
>   compound-statement in its function body is empty (12.6.2). If that
>   user-written constructor would be ill-formed, the program is
>   ill-formed. Each expression in the expression-list is of the form
>   `static_cast<T&&>(p)`, where `p` is the name of the corresponding
>   constructor parameter and `T` is the declared type of `p`.

Thus the corresponding user-written constructor is

```
B::B(int x) : A(static_cast<int&&>(x)) { }
```

which is well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to compile with clang, but not gcc (at least on my machine). Even with, gcc, however, the [code compiles and works fine](http://ideone.com/Q5m3ll) if you simply add a `explicit A()` constructor to the base class.

**EDIT** Apparently, as pointed out in the comment by @T.C., this is a [known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58751) in GCC.