# Getting error can not inherit constructors from indirect base in c++17 compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, c++17

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <chrono>    

class A{
    public:
        A(){} // default constr

};

class B:public A{
    public:
    using A::A;
    protected:

};

class C:public B{
    public:
        using A::A; //scope resolution 

        int f1(A a);// dummy function

};

int main () 
{ 
    return 0; 
}
```

// Above program is working fine with C++ and C++14 but its giving error with C++17
   // why and how can it be resolved?

Comment: This is possibly answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399644/inheriting-constructors-and-virtual-base-classes

Comment: Both GCC 9.3 & Clang 10 reject the code with `-std=c++11`, `-std=c++14`, `-std=c++17`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, constructors could be inherited from only direct base class. [[namespace.udecl]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#3)

> If a [***using-declarator***](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.udecl#nt:using-declarator) names a constructor, its [***nested-name-specifier***](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.prim.id.qual#nt:nested-name-specifier) shall name a direct base class of the class being defined.

You can inherit constructors from `B` in class `C`; the constructors of `A` have been inherited in `B`, then they'll be inherited in `C` too.

```
class C : public B {
    public:
        using B::B;
        //    ^^^^
};
```